# AWS Cognito Authenticate Users with Firebase Email And Password IOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, firebase, amazon-cognito, firebase-authentication

I am having difficulty navigating Amazon's documentation. I currently have an app that logs in using Firebase's email and password identification. How do I connect this to my data stored in AWS using Cognito? My app is in Objective C.

Comment: Does your app have a backend? Or is it serverless?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately without a backend, you cannot integrate Firebase Login with Cognito since it doesn't support OpenId Connect.  With a backend, you would need to implement the [Developer Authenticated Identities](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html) flow as follows:

Implement AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider

In the refresh method:

1. Login via Firebase
2. Make a https call passing the Firebase Login
   token to your backend and validate
3. From your backend, call
   [GetOpenIdForDeveloperIdentity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity.html) using Developer Credentials
4. Pass
   results back to the device
5. Update the identity id and the logins map